# edges with thickness and color

Tags: rendering, materials, edges

Is there a way to vary the thickness and color of lines created by just edges and vertices?
I realize that a face can be defined and then color and material applied, but is there any way to apply a color to the edges?

Comment: What? It is very difficult to understand what you are asking. Please rephrase it.

Comment: I only have edges and vertices in an object.  Can I apply a color to the edges?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, apart from setting theme color and default line widths there is no way to color lines.

If this was necessary, it's possible to write a python script that draws an overlay on the mesh using custom-data to store colors on edges, but this is quite an involved solution and not really ideal, because higher detail meshes will draw more slowly(since Python is not very fast for these kinds of tasks).

Comment: Thanks.  The great Ideasman answered my question!  I guess I will make a face out of closely spaced edges and and color from there.

Comment: Isn't there a way to abuse a modal operator combined with glLineWidth(n) to force Blender to draw everything with extra edges? It's hacky and not very controllable though.