# Hide wireframe in edit mode

Tags: edit-mode, wireframe

I am editing a very dense mesh. It looks great when viewed as solid faces, but it's just a black blob when viewed as wireframe because there are so many vertices.

When I switch to edit mode to select some vertices, the display goes to wireframe. Is there a way to hide unselected "wires" in edit mode, but keep the solid display of all faces, so that I can work on this dense mesh?

Answer (score 2):

Sadly this is not possible, however you can approximate a result like this fairly easily.

First, go to *File > User Preferences > Themes > 3D View* and change the *Wire* color to the default grey. *(Around Hex 6B6B6B)*

[image: Change colors 1]

This will make it less visible, but not invisible. You can make it so that selected edges are not shown as well by going to the `N` menu and finding the *Mesh Display* options.

[image: Hide Selected Edges]

Also see [**this question**](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/699/edges-with-thickness-and-color)

Comment: is there a way to set a hotkey to the checkbox "Edges"? So that you can toggle it with a hotkey?